# UE5 OpenCV: Can’t grab VideoCapture

Tags: c++, opencv, unreal-engine5

I’m trying to read camera input using the built-in OpenCV library in UE5 but no matter what I do, I can’t seem to make cv::VideoCapture.read() return anything. cv::VideoCapture.grab() also returns false every time.

It works fine on the same machine with regular C++ with OpenCV 4.6.0 and the VideoCapture is definitely open and the camera turns on as expected.

Is there something about Unreal’s built-in implementation I need to know about? (Other than it used OpenCV 4.5.5). I can’t seem to find any info online about this.

This is what my header files look like:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "PreOpenCVHeaders.h"
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include "PostOpenCVHeaders.h"

#include "CameraReader.generated.h"
```

And my Plugin’s Build file:

```cs
PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(
    new string[]
    {
        "Core",
        "OpenCVHelper",
        "OpenCV",
        // ... add other public dependencies that you statically link with here ...
    }
);
```

Using Windows 11 with Kinect 2.0.

I thought maybe I was missing some OpenCV DLLs since I can only find a custom Unreal version of the OpenCV World DLL, so I tried overriding the default OpenCV plugin and  adding the FFMPEG and MSMF DLLs myself but that didn’t change anything.

Edit: After many attempted building OpenCV from source, I only managed to get GStreamer and FFMPEG to work.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCV library that comes with UE5 is not built with FFmpeg or with the Media Foundation library, so it cannot read video from a file or from a camera.
You can try to build your own version of OpenCV with FFmpeg or Media Foundation support and use that instead of the one that comes with UE5.

Comment: It took some time (first time using CMake and turns out v3.25.0-rc4 is busted), but I managed to get my own built version of OpenCV to work with Unreal, with more of the modules enabled. However, the camera is still not being grabbed. The videos work fine.